# Payment of Fees

Tags: mysql

I have four tables in my database:

- `student` : contain the student's ID and name, etc.
- `student_fee` : contains the *paid_date*, *student_id* and *fee_id* with references to the `student` and `fee` tables
- `fee` : contains the *fee_id*, fee amount, *fee_typeid* (ref to `fee_type` table)
- `fee_type` : contain the *fee_typeid* and type of fees - admission fee, monthly tuition fee, fines, uniform fees, etc.

How do I display the students who have already paid the admission fee (or *fee_typeid* for admission fee) and those who have not paid it?

Well .. English is not my first language ;)

Comment: SELECT student.name
FROM student
LEFT JOIN student_fee ON student.student_id = student_fee.student_id
left join fee on student_fee.fee_id = fee.fee_id
left join fee_type on fee.feetype_id = fee_type.feetype_id
WHERE fee_type.feetype_id = '4' AND student_fee.student_id IS NOT NULL i used this to retrieve who have paid but when i use IS NULL i could not retrieve the name who have not paid

Comment: Not a very descriptive title. (not my downvote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE student_id IN
    (
        SELECT student_id FROM student_fee WHERE fee_id IN
            (
                 SELECT fee_id FROM fee WHERE fee_typeid=?
            )
    )
```

I believe this is what you need.  This is a method of doing `join`s without actually writing the join syntax.

Basically, you are selecting all the *fee_id* where they are of the type that you want.  Then, you are selecting all the *student_id* where the *fee_id* matches the ones you just selected.  Finally, you pull all the information about the students whose *student_id* is one of the ids you just pulled.

Comment: This works.. very well just wondering why IS NULL does not work ...Thanks a lot